# Netbeans Java - You have an error in your sql syntax

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm getting this error when I go to update my database.[Error I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTX1S.png)

This is what my database looks like [Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MLWv.png)

And here is my code:

private void updatebtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

```
    try{
    String mid = midtxt.getText();
    String fname = firstnametxt.getText();
    String lname = lastname.getText();
    String nic = nictxt.getText();
    String Address = addresstxt.getText();
    String Telephone = telephonetxt.getText();   


    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    jXDatePicker1.setFormats(dateFormat);
    DateFormat sysDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
    String Dob  = sysDate.format(jXDatePicker1.getDate());



   String sql = "UPDATE `addmember` SET `FirstName`='"+fname+"',LastName`='"+lname+"',`NIC`='"+nic+"',`DOB`='"+Dob+"', `ADDRESS`='"+Address+"', `Telephone`='"+Telephone+"' WHERE MID='"+mid+"' ";
      try{
            Updater(sql);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Values Updated");
        }
        catch( Exception ex){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
        }
    }

    catch(Exception ex){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not concatenate values into a query string, use prepared statements with parameter placeholders. Your current code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing backtick before `LastName`.

Comment: Thank you bro! I'm blind as a bat

Comment: @NathanDeLima Missing semicolons and friends are always the worst errors. ;)